# Where is the syntax error in this MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to set the output parameter name to the concatenated kund.Vorname and kund.Nachname. But I get a syntax error and I can't find it. I'd appreciate any help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetName(IN kartennummer CHAR(16), OUT name VARCHAR(91))
BEGIN
SELECT @name = (CONCAT_WS(' ', kund.Vorname, kund.Nachname)
  FROM Kunden kund,
       Konten kont
  WHERE kund.KundenID = kont.KundenID AND
        kont.Kartennummer = kartennummer));
END;
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: Count ( and ). Same number?

Comment: You can usen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61681752/5193536  it s the same home work

Comment: Show us the error message; it says exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @nbk: are the instructor's initials "nbk" by some odd coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

You are closing too many brackets on line 3

Answer (score 0):

First you're using name without a leading @ and in the Select Statement @name. That's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

And, depending on context, you may need a `DELIMITER` statement.